# SocketのInputStream、OutputStreamはスレッドセーフでしょうか？

Tags: java

SocketのInputStream、OutputStreamはスレッドセーフでしょうか？

以下のようなコードで、ソケットの送信処理（outputStram.writeメソッド）は、複数のスレッドから呼び出す場合は、排他制御が必要でしょうか？
例えばスレッドAでメッセージを返信しているときに、
何かしらの理由で、スレッドBがエラーメッセージを返信し、outputStreamをクローズしてもよいものでしょうか？
（クローズした場合、スレッドAの送信処理は中断されるのでしょうか。）

・スレッドAの処理

```
ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(0);
Socket socket = serverSocket.accept(); // ブロッキングされる（クライアントからの通信開始要求が来るまで待機）
OutputStream outputStream = new BufferedOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
outputStream.write(送信データ);
```

・スレッドBの処理

```
outputStream.write(エラーメッセージ);
outputStream.close();
outputStream = null;
```

よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

一般にI/OStreamはスレッドセーフではありません。

また、close()すると他のスレッドも切断されます。
writeの最中に別スレッドからclose()したときに、通信が切断されるまでに送りきれるどうかはわかりませんが、そういう設計は避けるべきでしょう。

ただし、SocketのInputStreamとOutputStreamはおおよそ独立しています。
Socket全体で同期するのではなく、InputStreamとOutputStreamそれぞれで同期させる（IとOそれぞれを1つのスレッドからのみ操作する）のがパフォーマンス的に有利になるでしょう。

Comment: ありがとうございます。
そういう設計は避け、IとOそれぞれを一つのスレッドで操作することが望ましいこと理解できました。
すっきりしました。アカウントが取れ次第、当QAのクローズ処理をします。